# JSON Array Response

Tags: php, android, json, jsonobjectrequest

I cant get Array from mysql database (name, lastname and age). My web service is working, but im not getting any response in android app.

This is my php file:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showStudent();
}

function showStudent()
{
    global $connect;

    $query = " Select * FROM demo; ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array  = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("demo"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

My php is generating json array i tested it. This is my problematic JSONObjectRequest in android app:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("ww");
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        showUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONArray demos = response.getJSONArray("demo");
                            for (int i = 0; i < demos.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject demo = demos.getJSONObject(i);

                                String firstname = demo.getString("name");
                                String lastname = demo.getString("lastname");
                                String age = demo.getString("age");

                                tvResult.append(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age + " \n");
                            }
                            tvResult.append("===\n");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.append(error.getMessage());

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Any help is welcomed, i didnt find any solutions. My guess is that this nullable parametar is messing sth up, but if i remove it im getting whole bunch of errors.

Comment: Could you please  add the Json you are receiving, I mean this data  echo json_encode(array("demo"=>$temp_array));

Comment: first check your json url display result ?

Comment: RECIVING JSON:Connected successfully{"demo":[{"id":"1","name":"ivan","lastname":"boss","age":"25"},{"id":"2","name":"$name","lastname":"$lastname","age":"0"},{"id":"3","name":"ivan","lastname":"mbfdgd","age":"25"},{"id":"18","name":"juro","lastname":"duro","age":"0"},{"id":"19","name":"juro","lastname":"6","age":"0"},{"id":"23","name":"kkk","lastname":"hh","age":"7"},{"id":"24","name":"kkk","lastname":"hh","age":"7"}]}

Comment: @IvanBošnjaković works or not?

Comment: @IvanBošnjaković I have deleted my answer , I´m going to implement it again,one question :
System.out.println(response.toString()); print the Json you are receiving

Comment: @IvanBošnjaković your code was ok, sorry I did not copy your Json correctly, in my end works perfectly with the json in local, so the problem probably is in the Json you are receiving